# why is the address displayed instead of the name?

Tags: c++

don't pay too much attention to the logic of the code, quickly made for an easier example!

for example i have a container that contains pointers on my Order, and i have a possibility to show my all orders.I try to do it but i get adrress of idk what

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Order {
public:
    static std::list <Order*> orders;
    std::string order;
public:
    Order(std::string ORDER) {
        this->order = ORDER;
    }
```

to make some orders :

```
    static void makeOrder(std::string item) {
        Order* order = new Order(item);
        orders.push_back(order);
    }
```

to show my orders :

```
    static void showOrder() {
        std::list<Order*>::iterator it;

        for ( it = orders.begin(); it != orders.end(); it++ ) {
            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

std::list <Order*> Order::orders;


int main() {
    Order::makeOrder("Knife");
    Order::showOrder();
}
```

how to make the "knife" come out?

Comment: Hint: in `std::cout << *it << std::endl;` what is the type of `*it`?

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use your debugger. You don't need anyone's help to figure out these mysteries, just the tool you already have installed on your computer, your debugger! Simply use your debugger to see what `*it` is, and everything should become crystal clear. Knowing how to effectively use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. You will not be able to write any C++ program of any considerable length without knowing how to use a debugger to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the value of a pointer, which is just a memory address.

```
std::cout << (*it)->order << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `std::cout << *it << std::endl;` with:

```
std::cout << (*it)->order << std::endl;
```

In the above modified statement, `*it` gives us a *pointer to Order* (`Order*`). Next we dereference that pointer which gives us an object of type `Order`. And finally we access the value of the `order` data member of that object.

#### Important

Also, don't forget to **free** the memory allocated on the heap(using `new`) using `delete`. Otherwise, you will have a **memory leak** in your program.